# Encrypting a File per IP address

Tags: encryption

I am looking for software that can encrypt the file per IP Address or Key?

Example: **songs.mp4** is the file

**songs.mp4** is downloaded to my mobile phone Note: the used mobile can only access or open the file. If the user share it to other device the file will not work. Is there any recommended software for this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: You're aware that, even if such an application would exist, the file would be unusable for you within a short time as its IP address is not static?

Comment: Do you want the mobile phone to encrypt the file during the download (without any involvement from the user), or should the phone-user manually encrypt it after download? Do you expect the user to select the file from within an app, using a  file-open dialog or similar?

Comment: For example: The user bought file [song.mp4] w/ verification id then he/she will send the verification + ip address to admin to grant the users mobile/pc ip adress.